# Types of deployment descriptors in Java EE programming and their use

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment-descriptor

I know there are two types of deployment descriptors in Java EE programming.

```
1. Java EE deployment descriptor
2. Runtime deployment descriptor
```

Is it possible to create both types of descriptors for all levels of artifacts: (i.e. component, module, application)?

Also, for the two types, can I prefer one to another? Or, are there situations where I need to use both types?

Comment: Java EE has deployment descriptors for most things that could be declared using annotations and more than a few things that can't.  Because the scope of Java EE is broad, the scope of the answer to your question is broad ... and beyond the intended scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks, but I did not bring in the idea of annotations here. I was referring to deployment descriptors of two types.